# Android SDK and AVDmanager giving errors

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have  64bit system and have downloaded SDK and the manager to learn Android development.
As you can see I am neewbie and I am having few hiccups.

1. I have downloaded and succesfully installed the plugin for Eclipse.
2. But when it comes to manager when I am downloading basic packages, I get the error in the screenshot.
3. I have made sure to fetch the url using http.
4. the error seems the installer is not able to access its own folder, which is quite surprising.

Are there any permission which I have to change?

I have also included a screenshot for the convenience:

[Screen shot http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/1108/capturempk.png](http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/1108/capturempk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just two quick things to check:

- Make sure you are not running this from within your "Program Files" folder. Run it in Documents or somewhere as Vista & Win7 try to protect any Program Files and folders.
- Right click the application and look for the option to always run it as administrator. Even in Linux based operating systems you need to run this updater as administrator some times.

These are just two quick solutions, just in case.

Comment: no both dint help me in any way.. i by default run them only as administrator so that clause is out of question .

Comment: i just wrote in my problem i did both

Comment: Ah ok. I missed that. You misspelled HTTPS and just wrote HTTP, which would mean that it is unticked, hence the confusion. Are you updating through eclipse or going straight to the android.exe file?